# Handling With Concurrent Duplicate Requests

Tags: rest, api, http

I have a REST endpoint called `CancelOrder`. It comprises four steps (in order):

1. Cancel fulfilment (Calls a downstream service).
2. Cancel the quote (Calls a downstream service).
3. Update the state of the order to `cancelled` (In our local database).

This is a `PUT` operation and hence, I am trying to make it idempotent and fail-safe.

Scenario 1:

1. **Just a single call**:

   Cancels the fulfilment, cancels the quote, updates the state. All's good.
2. **A call is midway when a different call is received. Assume no pessimistic locking is present**:

   The state of the order has not been changed to 'cancelled' by the previous call yet, but the fulfilment has been cancelled. Now, when the second call tried to cancel the fulfilment, it returns an error.

The ideal way to handle the above scenario is making the API transactional by acquiring a write lock on the document on each call. But I don't want to do that.

How should I handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways (among a lot of other solutions) to deal with this scenario:

Solution A:

1. Add a new state in order as `isCanceling`. After server receives the first cancel request on an order, set this state as `true`. Once the cancel operation is finished, set this state as `false`.
2. If server receives another cancel request on the same order, but find its status is `isCanceling`, server would return `102 Processing` to client, indicating the operation is in-progress.

Solution B:

1. same as step 1 in Solution A.
2. Everytime when server receives the cancel request (including the first one), a listener is added in that order's queue, waiting to be notified by event "Cancel-OK" or "Cancel-Fail".
3. If server receives cancel request on an order, but find its status is `isCanceling`, server would do nothing but just add corresponding listener in the above queue.
4. Once cancel operation is finished (success or fail), an event is fired. All the listeners in the queue will get the message, and HTTP response would be returned for all the previous pending HTTP requests.

Personally, I prefer Solution B.

Comment: This is a nice solution but requires that I update the order document adding one more call to the DB. I don't want to add any more latency. Any other method that you suggest?

Comment: Well, you can add this "isCanceling" status to memory database, such as Redis. In this way, the latency cost would be low.